# Mac OSX equal to linux time command

Tags: command-line, bash

What's binary that will give exact result for Linux's `time` command flags?

```
alias tcmd='/usr/bin/time \-f\ "CPU: %Us\tReal: %es\tRAM: %MKB"'
```

Current `time` in Mac OSX for command above is:

```
/usr/bin/time: illegal option -- f
usage: time [-lp] command.
```

Comment: Why not set the `TIMEFORMAT` variable and use `bash`'s builtin `time`.

Comment: I've tried `export TIMEFORMAT="CPU: %Us\tReal: %Es\tRAM: %MKB"` but it shows `-bash: TIMEFORMAT: 'M': invalid format character`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Nevermind, found it:

```
brew install gnu-time
```

the command is `gtime`

Comment: Great! Please mark this as solved.

Comment: Awesome, added this to my list of fresh install items for any new Mac OS

Comment: I use this in my .zshrc: `alias time='gtime'`